# Can I reorder "My Library" items in my Amazon Instant Video library?

Tags: amazon

I have about 20 movies or so in my Amazon streaming video library.

By default, in the `My Library` section of the Amazon channel on my Roku or my Vizio Smart TV, the videos seem to show up - I think - in reverse chronological order by date purchased.

I would ***like*** to be able to reorder my library, so that I can put related movies together in the Amazon channel on my various devices. For example, I'd like the put all the **MARVEL** universe movies together; or all of the `Lord of the Rings` movies together.

I do believe this is an ordering that comes from Amazon's side of things, not the device, as they show up in the same order on all my devices.

Is there anywhere in Amazon where you can reorder your library? I poked around a little bit, but couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. P.D. It was bumped by an answer that was deleted.